# bootstrap date formate getting wrong result

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap

i want date formate in dd/MM/yyyy

using js and css

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
```

my jquery script

$(function () {
            $('#DateOfBirth').datetimepicker({
                format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
            });
        });

but output is

Tu/00/yyyy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your format should be like this: "DD/MM/YYYY"

```js
$(function () {
    $('#DateOfBirth').datetimepicker({
        format: "DD/MM/YYYY"
    });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/e8bddc60e73c1ec2475f827be36e1957af72e2ea/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>


<div style="position: relative">
  <input type="text" id="DateOfBirth" class="form-control" />
</div>
```